# I'm trying to use a regular expression but it doesn't work. Give me a hint

Tags: javascript

Write a function that will find all words in a string that end with the letters 'a' and then replace the characters in between with '!'. Between the letters a can be any character (except a).Write a function that will find all words in a string that end with the letters 'a' and then replace the characters in between with '!'. Between the letters a can be any character (except a).

```
let readline = require('readline');
let rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});

rl.on('line', function(input) {             
    function replaceInA (argument) {
        let a = "aba accca azzza wwwa".replace(/^a.+?a$/, '!');
        return a
    }
    const someString = input;
    let result = replaceInA(someString);
    console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested (and I haven't considered the edges cases)

I assumed a case-insensitive matching and used lookahead and lookbehind and captouring group and replace to count the "!"

```js
let regEx=/(?<=a)([^(a|\s)]+)(?=a)/ig;
let test = "aba accca azzza wwwa"

let testResult = test.replace(regEx,replaceCustom);
function replaceCustom(match,p1){
  return "!".repeat(p1.length);
}

console.log(testResult)
```

Comment: Sample Input:

aba accca azzza wwwa
Sample Output:
                          
a!a a!!!a a!!!a wwwa 
sorry, but in my browser it throws an error

Comment: you had specify that between "a" was possible any character (thereby included spaces), ok I try to refactoring my regular expression. However with that Input you have to get : a!a!a!a!a!a!a   If you have an error may be you have an old browser

Comment: I modified my answer according to your clarification. You should modify your initial question with with these clarifications